# MVC.net session gets mixed between users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-state, session-variables

I am storing user objects in session, pulling them out in the controllers, and sometimes write some data into them. but when to users post at the same time, the sessions get mixed fro some reason.

Does anyone have any idea how that is possible ?

typical post:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(QuestionModel model, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var person = ((Person)Session["Person"]);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Global.Global.error);
            return View(new QuestionModel(person.page, (CultureInfo)Session["culture"]));
        }
        person.page = model.Page;
        while (person.Answers.Count > model.Page - 1)
        {
            person.Answers.RemoveAt(person.Answers.Count - 1);
        }
        var answer = new Answer() { answer = model.ChosenAnswer, Question = "Q" + person.page };
        person.Answers.Add(answer);
        if (!CheckForNextPage(person.page)) { person.hasFinishedQuestions = true; return RedirectToRoute("Result"); }
        person.page++;
        return View(new QuestionModel(person.page, (CultureInfo)Session["culture"]));
    }
```

I echo the session id on every page, and when a couple of users are using the website they get each others session + sessionid ...

@update: 3 experienced developers have been looking for the problem for 2 days, still no solution. already removed about 95% off the code, still same issue. server posts back responses from another session

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application_AcquireRequestState session is shared between users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604666/application-acquirerequeststate-session-is-shared-between-users) - Edit your original instead of making a new one.

Comment: I didn't use  Application_AcquireRequestState here. I removed the code from that function, but I still need to know if it could have to do with both @jfar: very constructive, altough 2 different problems with same outcome

Comment: I can't post my code, it's about 20.000 lines ... what code are you interested in

Comment: @Nealv - I don't understand.  You removed the code but you want to know if it could have to do with both?

Comment: Closed the previous question as dupe, so please nobody vote to close as dupe this one.  As to the reason this is happening... It shouldn't.  Never.  I'd guess you're using statics somewhere in the rest of your code.  You should not have anything marked as "static" in any of the objects which you expect to be used by different sessions.

Comment: I have 0 statics in code (except for 2 htmlhelpers which I don't use on those pages, and don't acces session data, and my generated resource files)

Comment: Also, why was this downvoted? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Nealv You can't ask a new question about the same thing each time you change something about your code.  Ask the general question, and through edits and answers and comments, you can find out whether or not your approach is sound.

Comment: @Yes I understand, but I am pretty sure you can't keep bringing this up and have 50% off the comments beeing about how wrong it was of me, while the subject is already very clearly handled. this beeing while there is still no solution for the problem. So please I would politely want to ask to not give any more negative comments unless you can solve the issue at the same time

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same behavior in our Orchard CMS based application where we use `Session` to store seach criteria... Thanks for putting this question out there which right now at least helps me not lose sanity, but the whole situation seems rather hopeless.

Comment: Turns out, our problem was caused by our own code. We were holding references to some objects beyond request scope and the values in there were being shared by multiple users. Oh boy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We "solved" it. We didn't actually solve it, but we copied all the sources to a new project, recompiled, and everything worked. Untill this day, we still don't know why, and how that error happened ...

Comment: Good to know that this worked, although of course it's a rather unconventional fix ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. 
So this is my guess:
You are testing this wrongly, you are using different tabs from the same browser. 
Some people don't know that this doesn't create a different session.

Try testing this on 2 different browsers (i.e. firefox and chrome) as they will not share the session (as the session id is normally stored in a cookie).

Please report back if this was the case.

Comment: we are testing in 2 browsers on 3 different computers at the same time. We have 0 statics, the only thing that is left that I can think of is that I post variables that are linked to the session to my model (altough this shouldnt be a problem)  View(new QuestionModel(person.page, (CultureInfo)Session["culture"]));

Comment: even weirder, on the above function, I post my data and when I look at the headers, i get ASP.NET_SessionId=s5ckrnnzezuijcivhfnqxg45 which is posted back.;
when I echo my response session id I get someone elses ....., and when I hit post again, my session is restored. It's like everything is ok, but the response I get is someone elses

Comment: Also, it's sometimes worthwhile to switch to "Private Browsing" or "Anonymous Browsing" mode (name depends on the browser), which will make sure that whatever persistent session id cookies may be hanging around are not in play.

Comment: In a case as weird as this I would search my project using "Search in Files" in the whole solution and using Regular expressions for this string "Session[^\\[]", this will avoid to show you all results when you are merely accessing Session variables. I would skim trough the results to see if there is some weird thing you are doing with the session. Like some custom session provider etc.

Comment: Ok, I have removed all acces to session. only thing that is left is <%=Session.SessionID %> in the page. still, the same problem. I get the  response from someone elses post, with his session key ... Could this have to do with globalisation and resx which are static ?

Comment: Globalisation is not connected to this.

Comment: The tone of this answer is not very helpful. Saying **This is not possible.** puts the poster in a weird situation of feeling stupid and having to defend himself. We're talking about software - and even professional framework software such as ASP.NET may (and does) contain bugs. This site is to help people finding a way to solve their problem, even weird, rare, improbable ones.